# Create a Measure by counting distinct rows of a table variable

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I ask for your help in something that seems pretty simple, but I´m unable to find an answer.
I want to calculate, in a card visualization, the nº of different values that exist on a particular column in my dataset.
The particularity of this column ("Supplier") is that accepts multiple values, separated by a comma. For example, consider the simple table at the bottom of the post.

In this particular case, the result should be 11. i want to do it without having to create a new table in my model or modify my current dataset.

I´m trying to combine the following steps, without success:
1º create a table variable with only 1 column that gathers the different values of Supplier.
Should be:

```
Variable Table_Column1
54
216,549
992,97,769,1125,1127
823
96
93
```

2º in the new table, add new rows for each different value on each row (Generateseries?)
Should be:

```
Variable Table_Column1
54
216
549
992
97
769
1125
1127
823
96
93
```

3º count the distinct number of rows
Distinctcount (Variable Table_Column1) = 11

Im very confused right now and I dont know how to use the column of my new table variable in the distinctcount.

Please help
thank you in advance

```
Supplier
54
Null 
216,549
992,97,769,1125,1127
823
96
Null
823
93
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to do this in Power Query:

In Power Query, split your column by `,` into new Rows...
[image]
(sorry that the image is showing `/` for the separator, it should be comma.)

Then you'll have it.

---

If you really need a DAX measure, then try this:

```
Supplier count = 
  var tblPath =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
      ADDCOLUMNS(
        DISTINCT('YourTable'[Supplier]),
        "iPath", SUBSTITUTE( 'YourTable'[Supplier], ",", "|")
      ),
      "iPathLength", PATHLENGTH([iPath])
    )
  var tblPathCum = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
      tblPath,
      "cumLength", SUMX( FILTER(tblPath, [iPath] <= EARLIER([iPath])), [iPathLength])
    )
  var tblGen = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      ADDCOLUMNS(
        GENERATESERIES(1, SUMX(tblPath, COALESCE([iPathLength], 0) ) ),
        "cum", MINX( FILTER(tblPathCum, [cumLength] >= [Value]), [cumLength] )
      ),
      "items", MAXX( FILTER(tblPathCum, [cumLength] = [cum]), [iPath] ),
      "itemNum", [cum] - [Value] + 1
    )
  var tblItem = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      tblGen,
      "item", PATHITEM( [items], [itemNum])
    )

  return COUNTROWS( DISTINCT(tblItem) )
```

The key behind this is leveraging the DAX [Parent and Child functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parent-and-child-functions-dax), `PATHLENGTH` and `PATHITEM`. These work with a pipe delimited string, hence the `SUBSTITUTE` from `,` to `|`.

Comment: Hi Sam,
thank you for your quick response.
Yes, that´s an option that i eventually had to use and i confirm it works. However, I would really appreciate to do it through a dax formula if that´s even possible.

Comment: I've added a DAX measure solution to the answer.